# SaaS Form asks this: "How is your application architected"

Tags: php, architecture

I've got some forms I'm filling out for my boss regarding our SaaS application, but I'm not quite sure how best to answer them. One of the questions is "How is your application architected" to which I've answered "Object-Oriented MVC" ... is this an appropriate response or am I misunderstanding the question

Answer (score 1):

Look at this:
http://highscalability.com/blog/category/example
you might want to come up with equivalent structure for your application stack. There are some good real-world examples there.

To be more specific, you might want to list at least the following for your application:

- What programming language/database/javascript or css frameworks are you using?
- What does your application server look like (how many servers? their configurations like processor/memory etc.)
- what kind of database servers are you using (how many and how much memory)
- What is your web server OS/software (Apache/NGinx or Windows server?)
- What kind of caching mechanism are you using (if you are using one)
- What is your backup and replication process
- What kind of version control you are using.
- Are you using any CDN?
- What kind of testing and deployment mechanism you are using.

These are some of the things that I can think of but you can always customize this list based on your application. Hope this helps.